# Is it safe to use hton[l|ll] and memcpy to pack signed integers into network packets

Tags: c, network-programming

Protocols standardised by the IETF tend to use big-endian byte order when packing integers into network packets and mention this explicitly, but IETF protocols which use signed integers such as [Diameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6733#section-4.2) seem to be silent on how the signed integers should be represented on-the-wire, should we just assume two's complement?

When packing signed integers in C, is it ok to cast to an unsigned integer of the same width and use the standard `hton()/htonl()/htonll()` and `memcpy()` combo?

Comment: Why is this tagged C11 or even C? The C standard has nothing to say about networks.

Comment: `uinteger = (uint32_t)-sinteger;
        uinteger |= 0x80000000;` looks wrong.  it is mapping `[1 ... 0x7FFFFFFF, 0x80000000]` to `[0x80000001... 0xFFFFFFFF,0x80000000]` in the second line -of code.  What are you trying to do here?  I'd expect `uinteger = 0x7FFFFFFFu-sinteger;`

Comment: @JensGustedt example code is C.  Unsure as to whether the C standards talk about how integers are laid out in memory, and how their sign should be represented.

Comment: @chux uinteger = (uint32_t)-sinteger unsets the sign bit, and assigns the unsigned value to a 32bit integer.

uinteger |= 0x80000000 sets the most significant bit of the most significant byte. 

The point of the question is to determine whether it's safe to copy the signed integer directly into the packet, or whether extra work needs to be done, because the in-memory representation of sign might change between systems.

Comment: "uinteger = (uint32_t)-sinteger unsets the sign bit" is not true when `sinteger == 0x80000000`.

Comment: Yes, there is that corner case, and the on-the-wire representation would need to be 2's complement which the example code didn't do.

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell Your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825585/is-it-safe-to-use-htonlll-and-memcpy-to-pack-signed-integers-into-network-pac?noredirect=1#comment74704499_43825585) is unclear.  The sample code is 2's complement.

Comment: I don't believe it was.  The on-the-wire output would have been sign-magnitude, not two's complement.

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell Hmmm. The code used `int32_t` - that is _only_ 2's complement.

Comment: @chux yes but it cast it to a uint32_t first (after negative the value), and copied the value from the uint32_t to the uint8_t buffer.

Comment: As to the question, since you are using 2's complement types with no padding, reordering the bytes with `hton[l|ll]` is "safe".

Comment: If you want to add that as an answer i'll mark it as correct.